# How to Upload multiple files after form submit using backbone.js save() method?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, backbone.js, laravel

I am using backbone as java script framework. I have a form, I want to upload upto 10 images at the same time. I am also giving enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag and using

```
<form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type="file" name="file1"/>
   <input type="file" name="file2"/>
</form>
```

On file change, I am using using HTML5 FileReader() to read the file. And then when i submit the form i want to save all the formdatas. And I have to upload these images to  'uploads/images' directory. As I mentioned, I am using backbone, so when my form submits, I prevent the page reloading using  e.preventDefault(). After that,

```
     var savemyForm = Backbone.View.extend(){
     id: '#form_id",
     events: {
             'submit' : 'save'
     }
     save : function (e){
             e.preventDefault();
             var newproject = new App.Models.Project;
              newproject.save({

               // I have to pass values here. But how can i pass values of files. 
               // And that files where I am passing from here should be 
               // moveable to my '/uploads/directory' using the 
               // move_upload_file($destination_path, $filename);
             });     
   });
```

Comment: move them serversides?

Comment: What are you *asking* here? It sounds like you're just asking [how to handle the upload on the server side using PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just send AJAX post with your files from a multipart form to your serverside script that handles the file writing! It's a smart thing to use the jQuery.forms plugin so your fileuploads are IE compatible too.

- http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Then post your form to a route and process it with a Laravel serverside script like this:

```
public function create() {
   $file = Input::file('file');
   $file_upload = new FileUpload;
   $file_upload->name = Input::get('name');
   $file_upload->path = $this->settings['destination_folder'];
   $file_upload->extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $file_upload->mimetype = $file->getMimeType();
   $file_upload->file_size = $file->getSize();
   if (exif_imagetype($file)) {
      list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
      $file_upload->dimensions = $width . " x " . $height;
   }
   $file_upload->save();
   $file->move($this->settings['destination_folder'], $file_upload->name);
}
```

This is a snippit of the code I use to write files in Laravel. In your case you would have to create some for loop for adding multiple files.

Some info on how to setup and use RESTful controllers in Laravel:

- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785
- http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

I would advise you to first try to upload one file successfully and if that works out try multiple. From one to multiple is not rocket science. ;)

Comment: But, I couldn't access using Input::file('file') by using backbone. That is the real problem

Comment: The idea is that you do a post from your front end to an API endpoint. It doesn't matter what kind of JavaScript frond end technology you use. And no you can not use your serverside framework in your clientside code! :)

Comment: Do you already have an API i.e. RESTful controller in Laravel which you are using?

Comment: Yes. I have. I am using RESTful controller

Comment: OK cool, well then you should setup a route like api.example.com/api/files which should be a post. Then in the resource contoller the store() function will be called. There you can use a variation of the code I posted. You should really see your front end apart from your back end. They are only connect through the route.

Comment: I will help you make this work! I will be using something like this soon so! :)